# MongoDB sort query result by creationdate and then only take the first document for each unique ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a mongodb containing submissions with the unique _id parameter. I want to get all submissions that have specific parameters x = y (fictional), sort them by the creation date and then reduce the result to only contain the newest submission for each id. I think I need to use an aggregation to sort the results but I dont know how to continue.

So, currently I have:

```
Submission.find({x: y}).aggregate(
{
    $sort: {_id: -1}
},  .....)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Submission.sample.aggregate([{$match: {x: y}}, {$sort: {createdDate: 1}}, {$project: {x: 1, createdDate: 1}}])
```

Here is the sample code using aggregation pipeline. First, find documents that have x property with y value, then sort by createdDate property, and finally get only attributes you want to reduce returned object size.